# Spring 5 WebClient using ssl

Tags: spring, ssl, reactive-programming, self-signed, spring-webflux

I'm trying to find examples of WebClient use.

My goal is to use Spring 5 WebClient to query a REST service using https and self signed certificate

Any example?

Comment: that page is gone

Answer (score 53, accepted):

See example of use [insecure TrustManagerFactory](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/util/InsecureTrustManagerFactory.html) that trusts all X.509 certificates (including self-signed) without any verification. The important note from documentation:

> Never use this TrustManagerFactory in production. It is purely for testing purposes, and thus it is very insecure.

```
@Bean
public WebClient createWebClient() throws SSLException {
    SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();
    ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext) )
    return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector).build();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I also need to set timeout on read and connection, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Have one comment though. The last line should be WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector).build(); otherwise won't compile.

Comment: This solution stopped working after upgrading Spring Boot to 2.1.0 which brings in Spring 5.1.1, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53147631/2172731 this worked for me using Spring Security 5.1.1.

Answer (score 60):

Looks like Spring 5.1.1 (Spring boot 2.1.0) removed `HttpClientOptions` from `ReactorClientHttpConnector`, so you can not configure options while creating instance of `ReactorClientHttpConnector`

One option that works now is:

```
val sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build()
val httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure { t -> t.sslContext(sslContext) }
val webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build()
```

Basically while creating the HttpClient, we are configuring the **insecure** *sslContext*, and then passing this httpClient for use in `ReactorClientHttpConnector` globally.

**The other option** is to configure `TcpClient` with insecure sslContext and use it to create `HttpClient` instance, as illustrated below:

```
val sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build()
val tcpClient = TcpClient.create().secure { sslProviderBuilder -> sslProviderBuilder.sslContext(sslContext) }
val httpClient = HttpClient.from(tcpClient)
val webClient =  WebClient.builder().clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build()
```

For more information:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor
- https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/util/InsecureTrustManagerFactory.html

**Update: Java version of the same code**

```
SslContext context = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
    .build();
                
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(context));

WebClient wc = WebClient
                    .builder()
                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
```

Comment: "_The other option is to configure TcpClient with insecure sslContext and use it to create HttpClient instance_" seems to be broken with the release of Spring Boot 2.4.0 (reactor-netty 1.0.1). You need to either add `httpClient = httpClient.secure(tcpClient.configuration().sslProvider());` to carry on using `TcpClient` or use `HttpClientConfig` as a workaround until the fix for [reactor-netty#1382](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1382) gets released.

Answer (score 18):

**Had to edit this, to accommodate spring-boot 2.0->2.1 changes.**

Another way, if you want to program production code is, to create a spring bean like such, that modifies the injected WebClient, using the settings from the spring-boot server for where the truststore and Keystore are.  In the client, you only need to give the Keystore, if you are using 2-way-ssl. Not sure, why the ssl-stuff is not preconfigured and easily injectable, similar to the really cool spring-boot server settings.

```
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext;
import io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder;
.
.
.

  @Bean
  WebClientCustomizer configureWebclient(@Value("${server.ssl.trust-store}") String trustStorePath, @Value("${server.ssl.trust-store-password}") String trustStorePass,
      @Value("${server.ssl.key-store}") String keyStorePath, @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}") String keyStorePass, @Value("${server.ssl.key-alias}") String keyAlias) {

      return (WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) -> {
          SslContext sslContext;
          final PrivateKey privateKey;
          final X509Certificate[] certificates;
          try {
            final KeyStore trustStore;
            final KeyStore keyStore;
            trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(trustStorePath)), trustStorePass.toCharArray());
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStorePath)), keyStorePass.toCharArray());
            List<Certificate> certificateList = Collections.list(trustStore.aliases())
                .stream()
                .filter(t -> {
                  try {
                    return trustStore.isCertificateEntry(t);
                  } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error reading truststore", e1);
                  }
                })
                .map(t -> {
                  try {
                    return trustStore.getCertificate(t);
                  } catch (KeyStoreException e2) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Error reading truststore", e2);
                  }
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            certificates = certificateList.toArray(new X509Certificate[certificateList.size()]);
            privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, keyStorePass.toCharArray());
            Certificate[] certChain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(keyAlias);
            X509Certificate[] x509CertificateChain = Arrays.stream(certChain)
                .map(certificate -> (X509Certificate) certificate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .toArray(new X509Certificate[certChain.length]);
            sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                .keyManager(privateKey, keyStorePass, x509CertificateChain)
                .trustManager(certificates)
                .build();
  
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
            ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
            webClientBuilder.clientConnector(connector);
          } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        };
  }
```

Here the part, where you use the Webclient:

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Component
public class ClientComponent {

  public ClientComponent(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder, @Value("${url}") String url) {
    this.client = webClientBuilder.baseUrl(solrUrl).build();
  }
}
```

Comment: When the WebClientBuilder is injected into the component, it will automatically be customized with the WebClientCustomizer bean?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  If I remember correctly, I could inject the WebClient directly in the nomral application, but had to get it from the builder for unit-tests.  I didn't figure out, why this was, though, you might have to try - please feel free to correct this here, if you can get the WebClient directly.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I tried it both through injection and by explicitly creating an SslContext, which I passed as an option to a ReactorClientHttpConnector, which in turn I passed into the builder to build the WebClient. But the server I'm calling says I am not presenting a certificate. I double checked the keystores and truststores both client and server side and they are valid. Also, the server is accessible via RestTemplate configured for 2-way TLS as well as SOAP UI.

Comment: I fixed it but not sure why yours didn't work. I changed `.keyManager((PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, keyStorePass.toCharArray()))` to `.keyManager(keyManagerFactory)` after initializing a `KeyManagerFactory` with the keystore, and the server finally accepted the certificate.

Comment: I could test my old code, and the problem was, that it's apparently a difference between private key's certificateChain, and the trustchain, even if it contains the same keys.  The code I now posted is tested and worked, but ordering of the keys in the certificateChain can break the trustchain (at least I saw this happen).  Hopefully this is more helpful to others now.  I don't know why this standard usecase is so complicated.

Answer (score 5):

This one work for me. **Spring framework version 5.3.23 (Spring boot version 2.7.4)**  You can try this way using **ReactorClientHttpConnector**:

```
SslContext context = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
    .build();
                
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(context));

WebClient wc = WebClient
                    .builder()
                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();
```

hope this answer is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

For someone who might have stuck on how to consume a https protected REST API with reactive WebFlux **webClient**

You want to create two things

1. https enabled REST API - https://github.com/mghutke/HttpsEnabled
2. Another REST API as a client with WebClient to consume above one - https://github.com/mghutke/HttpsClient

Note: please go through above project look at keystore which is shared with Both the above spring boot apps. And programmatically added the keyManagerFactory and TrustManagerFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if we need to configure **multiple SSLContexts**, for example, we have REST API 1 and REST API 2 and for them we configured `SSLContext sslContext1` and `SSLContext sslContext2`

The thing is that `HttpClient.create().secure(...)` allows us to apply only one `SSLContext`, but in our case we want multiple.

So, the solution in our case would be to create two different `WebClient` with different `ReactorClientHttpConnector`

```
// for REST API 1 with sslContext1
WebClient webClient1 = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient.create()
                        .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext1))
        ))
        .build();

// for REST API 1 with sslContext2
WebClient webClient2 = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                HttpClient.create()
                        .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext2))
        ))
        .build();
```

And we're done!

Also, just to point out, these clients will share the event loop group by default, which is recommended. However, they won't, if you configure them using `runOn` or with using `ReactorResourceFactory`, more about resources can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-resources