# How to disable the security certificate check in Java webflux webclient requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

While making post/get requests through webflux webclient how can ssl check be disabled ?

Sample builder code which I'm using:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.github.v3+json")
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Spring 5 WebClient")
        .build();
```

In above code what change should be made to make ssl verification false ?

Comment: Would you have the option to import the server certificate to your JVM's trust store? Disabling the cert check altogether sort of defeats the purpose of using TLS.

Comment: here you can find what you are looking for, and remember this is very, very bad practice. Just for info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418523/spring-5-webclient-using-ssl

Answer (score 17):

```
        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();
    
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext));
    
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.github.v3+json")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Spring 5 WebClient")
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .build();
```