# Translate curl request to Spring flux WebClient

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, curl

I want to perform a rest call using `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient`

The correspondent `curl` command is this one:

```
curl -k --cert xxx.crt 
        --key yyy.key 
        --cacert ca.crt 
        -H "MyHEADER: userX" 
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
        https://host:1234/users -d '{"id":"XXXXX"}'
```

This is what I did so far:

```
 WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://host:1234");
 Mono<ClientResponse> result = client.get()
            .uri("/users")
            .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.add("MyHEADER","userX"))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .exchange();
```

How can I specify the certificates?

I tried to configure the sslContext following this: [Spring 5 WebClient using ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418523/spring-5-webclient-using-ssl) but I get the exception: `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure`

I suppose that I have to specify the client certificates for the SSL client authentication ( In the curl command I use --cert xxx.crt --key yyy.key). 
How can I do the same in Spring/java?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring 5 WebClient using ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418523/spring-5-webclient-using-ssl)

Comment: I tried to configure the sslContext as specified in the link you suggest but now I get an exception (I've updated my question with the new information)